# how to put words into a variables and check if it matches the data in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, search

I am using MSSQL and C# to write a search engine. I got a bunch of stop words in the database. In my default.aspx page, I got a textbox and a search button. Users can type in a whole sentence into the textbox.

I wrote the code for searching a single keyword but not a whole sentence. This is the function in default.aspx.cs

```
 private void ImageSearch()
{


    if (txtSearch.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        //when types nothing
        txtSearch.Focus();
        Warning.Text = "Please enter the keyword to search";
        //display message
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int check = Process.CheckStopWord(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
        //check if the keyword is stop word
        if (check == 0)
        {
            txtSearch.Focus();
            Warning.Text = "No stop word found";
        }
        else
        {
            txtSearch.Focus();
            Warning.Text = "Found Stop word";
        }

    }
}
```

and for the checkstopword function

```
public static int CheckStopWord(string keyword)
{
    string check = "0";
    string query = "SELECT COUNT (stopword) FROM stopwordtb WHERE [stopword] like '" + keyword + "'";
    //count how many stop word matches the keyword entered, return a string of a number
    accessDB dbaccess = new accessDB();
    DataSet ds = dbaccess.queryData(query);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == check)
    {
        return 0;
        //keyword != stop word in stopwordtb
        // begin search in image database - not implemented yet

    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
        //keyword = stop word in stopwordtb
    }

}
```

my problem is, what if the user type in a whole sentence?

For example, if he types in " The tree" in the textbox, but "The" is a stop word, so I will just ignore the "the" and just search the image database for "tree".

How can I put the sentence into variables and search each of them individually? or are there any faster way?

Hope somebody can give me some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you search in the database, you may first split the sentence, and then check each word is a stop word using a loop (ex: while-loop),

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like `string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');` then check each entry in the words array.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar function in c#. It Will accept a string or sentence ex:
INPUT: File access Mr Brown
OUTPUT: "'File' and 'access' and 'Mr' and 'Brown'"
Transleted to SQL: '"File" and "access" and "Mr" and "Brown"'

```
    private static string formatStringToSQLForFullTEXTSEARCH(string subject)
    {
                string[] subArray  = subject.Trim().Split(' ');
                string newSubject  = "";            

                newSubject = "";
                if (subArray != null && subArray.Length > 0)
                {
                    newSubject = "'" + subArray[0] + "'";
                    for (int i = 1; i < subArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        newSubject += " and '" + subArray[i]+"'";
                    }
                }
    return newSubject;
    }
```

Hope it helps somebody!